# Multiple html select and jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, select

I wanna create a multiple < select > with ajax and jquery.

First select(c1) is working properly. When I click on it returns another select(c2). But when I clicked on second select(c2) I can get third select(c3).

HTML:

```
<table><tr><td id="cat1div">
<select name="c1">
<option value="">---</option>
<option value="1">Auto</select>
<option value="2">Moto</select>
</td>
<td id="cat2div"></td>
<td id="cat3div"></td>
</tr></table>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("select[name=c1]").change(function () {
var id = $("select[name=c1] option:selected").val();

$.ajax({
            url: "category.php?cat=2&id=" + id, 
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#cat2div').html(html);
            }
        });

}); 



$("select[name=c2]").change(function () {
alert('asad');
var id = $("select[name=c2] option:selected").val();

$.ajax({
            url: "category.php?cat=3&id=" + id, 
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#cat3div select').html(html);
            }
        });

}); 

});
```

PHP:

```
<?if($_GET['cat']==2){?>
<select name="c2">
<option value="">---</option>
<?foreach($cat2[$_GET['id']] as $ca => $key){
?><option value="<?=$ca;?>"><?=$key;?><?}?>
</select>
<?}elseif($_GET['cat']==3){?>
<select name="c3">
<option value="">---</option>
<?foreach($cat3[$_GET['id']] as $ca => $key){
?><option value="<?=$ca;?>"><?=$key;?><?}?>
</select>
<?
```

Sorry for my English and thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select[name=c1]").change(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "category.php?cat=2&id=" + $(this).val(), 
      cache: false,
      success: function (html) {
        $('#cat2div').html(html).find("select[name=c2]").change(function () {
          $.ajax({
            url: "category.php?cat=3&id=" + $(this).val(), 
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
              $('#cat3div select').html(html);
            }
          }); 
        });
      }
    });
  }); 
});
```

Currently, when `$("select[name=c2]")` runs, the element isn't there yet...so there's nothing to bind a `change` handler to...you need to do this once the element *is* there, like I have above.

Comment: I don't know PHP but it looks to me as if those loops of his (or hers) to generate the `<select>` elements are always including `</select>` after each `<option>` ...