# Geodan's DualListbox : how to populate selected box with data from ArrayList

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, arraylist

I am writing an MVC applicaiton with a dual list box, with one side as Unselected Testers. On selection of testers, I am saving the data into a table. The problem is how to bind the saved data to the "Selected" box and the other list of users to the "Unselected" box.

The Data being fetched through JSON request and the response is an Array List so I cannot using selected in the `<option>` tag inside `<Select>` tag. Please see the below code.

How to populate the "Selected" box with data returned as ArrayList on a JSON Call.

```html
<div id="dual-list-box" class="form-group row">
  @*<select name="Testers" id="emp" multiple="multiple" data-title="employees" data-source='@Url.Action("AddTesterLookup")' data-value="index" data-text="name"></select>*@
  <select id="emp" multiple="multiple" data-title="employees" name="name" value="@Model.name" data-source='@Url.Action("AddTesterLookup")' data-value="index" data-text="name"></select>
</div>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('select').DualListBox();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're using a JS or PHP Framework, but for do that you should use javascript to run an Ajax query when the first select box it's changed.

That ajax should use the value of the first select box to get the elements you will populate with javascript in the second select box.

Check this as example:
[Multiple html select and jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147995/multiple-html-select-and-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

You have to data-json property set to false; and remove the data-source property. And fill the select inputs just like;

```
<select>
  <option>..</option>
  <option>..</option>
</select>
```